# VbScript click on button without id or name

Tags: button, vbscript, click

```html
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-empty yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup comment-action-buttons-renderer-thumb yt-uix-sessionlink sprite-comment-actions sprite-like i-a-v-sprite-like" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-label="Like" onclick=";return false;" type="button" data-action="CAUQAhojejEzd3R0cXFteGZmZGR5YzUyM3RqdjRhd3ZhYXd0Znd0MDQqC0UwWTRQd0F0cFY4MAA4AEoVMTAyNjU4MjM5NzEyNjczNTY0MzYzUAA%3D" data-sessionlink="itct=CNgCEPBbIhMI--Ox47yu0QIVwjwdCh0b8Q_b" data-url="/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1" data-sessionlink-target="/comment_service_ajax?action_perform_comment_action=1" data-action-type="like"></button>
```

I want to click on this button by data-action how can i do that ?
I don't know why code is in one line but i need to search for this.
data-action = "CAUQAhojejEzd3R0cXFteGZmZGR5YzUyM3RqdjRhd3ZhYXd0Znd0MDQqC0UwWTRQd0F0cFY4MAA4AEoVMTAyNjU4MjM5NzEyNjczNTY0MzYzUAA%3D"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Dim Node
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = 1
    .Navigate "file:///C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tmp\tmp.htm"
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
    For Each Node In .Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        If Node.getAttribute("data-action") = "CAUQAhojejEzd3R0cXFteGZmZGR5YzUyM3RqdjRhd3ZhYXd0Znd0MDQqC0UwWTRQd0F0cFY4MAA4AEoVMTAyNjU4MjM5NzEyNjczNTY0MzYzUAA%3D" Then Exit For
    Next
    If IsEmpty(Node) Then
        MsgBox "Element not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Element found" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Node.outerHTML
    End If
End With
```